# Seeding Users with Rails 7/devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am making a Rails 7/React application (a rudimentary POS system) in which I am utilizing the devise-api and devise-security gems for authentication and session limiting.  After reading other threads with similar issues and trying their solutions, I am still unsure of how to proceed further.

```
# models/user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :checks, dependent: :destroy
  validates :password, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :api,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :session_limitable
end
```

```
# db/migrate/devise_create_users.rb

class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name, null: false, default: ""
      t.string :last_name, null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
      t.boolean :admin, null: false, default: false
      t.string :unique_session_id
      t.timestamps null: false
  end
end
```

```
# db/seeds.rb
users = User.create!(
    [
        {
            first_name: "John",
            last_name: "Smith",
            password: "1111",
            password_confirmation: "1111",
            admin: true
        },
        {
            first_name: "Samuel",
            last_name: "Amity",
            password: "4000",
            password_confirmation: "4000",
            admin: false
        }
    ]
)
```

I get the following error when attempting to seed the database:

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.password
/home/samity/Development/code/phase-5/burghers/burghers_pos/db/seeds.rb:6:in `<main>'

Caused by:
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.password
```

I recognize exactly what the error is, but based on other documentation I have read the devise library should take in the password and password_confirmation attributes of the User and generate the encrypted_password attribute.  I have also edited the password length in initializers/devise.rb to be the range of 4..4.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `validates :password, presence: true, uniqueness: true`.  Rails is trying to see if that's the case, and there is just a password= method, not a password method.

You probably want `validates :encrypted_password, presence: true, uniqueness: true`.  I'm not sure if devise will do that for you in some configuration or if it's down to you.  Actually, on the far off chance that you get two encrypted passwords that are the same, you probably just want to let it go.  Otherwise you're going to tell a user that their password is already in use?  Then they know they can test that password against every other account and get in somewhere.